# searching through strings without using a find function python 3

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, text

How would I find the position of a letter in a string without using the find function.

Would I use a combination of range and a length function?

update: I'm trying to find the position of a character in a string without using the find function for instance ('c','cat') c is at position zero

Comment: Please specify the programming language you're talking about. :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `enumerate`:

```
>>> s = 'foobar'
>>> l = 'o'
>>> [i for i,j in enumerate(s) if j==l]
[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

This function does the same as the `find()` method of Python strings (for the whole string not allowing the optional `start`and `end`arguments):

```
def my_find(string_, letter):
    for index, sub in enumerate(string_):
        if sub == letter:
            return index
    return -1
```

Now:

```
>>> s = 'abcabc'
>>> s.find('b')
1
>>> s.find('x')
-1
>>> my_find(s, 'b')
1
>>> my_find(s, 'x')
-1
```

Comment: That won't work when `letter` is longer than one character.

Comment: Yes, one letter  means one character.  The OP did not ask for a substring search.